# dot in url giving an error

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

i am getting a 404 error when a dot comes in my url, for example: `http://example.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Mega-5.8`

here my entire htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-A-Z_]*).([a-z]*)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.%2/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_mobile.php?bid=$1&brandname=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ show_mobile.php?bid=$2&brandname=$1
```

kindly help me i have searched many questions but i didn't get any helpful which works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Tweak your regex to allow `DOT` after first hyphen:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([\w.-]+)/?$ show_mobile.php?bid=$2&brandname=$1 [L,QSA]
```